# .Bat file unable to run powershell 7

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd

I have set up a very simple .bat file to execute a couple of commands to save me typing them out every time, however the processes need to be run in powershell 7.

If i manually run powershell 7.0.3 and then run the commands everything work, however running the .bat script starting

```
powershell -Version 7.0.3 -Command {XXXXX};
```

presents me with a message "Cannot start Windows PowerShell version 7.0.3 because it is not installed."

If i try and run it without the version number then it runs in 5.1.x and this then fails as it requires 6+.

Comment: the exe for ps7 is NOT `powershell.exe` ... it is `pwsh.exe` ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**tl;dr**

As [Lee_Dailey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3080908/lee-dailey) notes, you must **use [`pwsh.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pwsh)**, not [`powershell.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe), **to start a version of *PowerShell [Core] v6+* and you must invoke the desired version's *specific executable*.**

In the simplest case:

```
pwsh -Command "XXXXX"
```

<sup>Note that I've replaced `{XXXXX}` with `"XXXXX"`, because you cannot directly execute *script blocks* (`{...}`) from *outside* PowerShell - just supply the commands as a *string*.</sup>

---

Given that - unlike with Windows PowerShell - **you can install *multiple* PowerShell [Core] versions *side by side***:

- Run `pwsh -version` (sic; see below) to report the version in your system's path (the instance that comes first among the directories listed in the `PATH` environment variable, `$env:PATH`).
- If it is *not* the one you want to target, you'll have to invoke it via its *full path*:

  - If you want to rely on the *standard installation location*, you can use the following on Windows for version 7.0:  `"C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7\pwsh.exe"`
  - To determine the target version's executable location reliably, open an interactive console for it and run `(Get-Process -Id $PID).Path`

---

**The `-Version` parameter of `powershell.exe`**, the *Windows PowerShell* CLI, **does *not* allow you to start just *any* PowerShell version**, only an *older* version of *Windows PowerShell*:

- In fact, the **only supported argument is `-Version 2`**, and even that will only succeed if you have previously installed the required legacy versions of .NET Framework.
- *Caveat*: While versions higher than v5.1 - the latest and last Windows PowerShell version - sensibly result in an *error* (the one you saw), ***unsupported* lower versions are *quietly ignored***; in effect, `-Version 1` and `-Version 2` will both start version 2.0, whereas `-Version 3`, `-Version 4` and `-Version 5` are effectively ignored and run v5.1 - verify with `$PSVersionTable.PSVersion`

While a **`-Version` parameter** still exists **in `pwsh.exe`**, the PowerShell [Core] v6+ CLI, its **meaning has changed**:
It **now simply *reports* a version number, namely the targeted executable's *own*** (and therefore takes no argument).